# I trying to use javascript functions to open and close a menu , but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to use javascript to open and close a menu, i already can open a blank div, but no matter what  i do, i can't make it close, i've tried like 5 diferents codes, and this is the one that worked best. It doesn't give any type of error(acording to the DevTools), it just don't remove the div that i created, i tried to use this (operator?) "!!", to check if the div really exists(i thought this was the problem), but again i failed, and now after 3 days of pain to make this work, i gave up  and come here to ask if you guys know what's wrong

```
const openMenu = document.querySelector('.menu-icon');

//to open
openMenu.addEventListener('click', () =>{
  var closeMenu = document.createElement('div');
  closeMenu.id = "closeMenu1";
  closeMenu.className = "closeMenu";
  closeMenu.style.width = "400px";
  closeMenu.style.height = "600px";
  closeMenu.style.borderRadius = "6px";
  closeMenu.style.position = "relative";
  closeMenu.style.top = "50%";
  closeMenu.style.left = "50%";
  closeMenu.style.backgroundColor = "#99aaa1";
  document.body.appendChild(closeMenu);
},{once: true});

const _closeMenu = document.querySelector('closeMenu1');

//to close

var closingMenu = !!document.querySelector('.closeMenu');

if (closingMenu) {
  console.log("this is", closingMenu);
    _closeMenu.addEventListener('click', () =>{
    _closeMenu.remove();
    });
  }
```

I also tried without the {once: true}, but it didn't work, also i'm pretty new to javascript, so yea, this is problably not the best way to do this, but anyways.

Comment: can't you just use modals?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? How does it behave exactly? Did you check your devtools console for error messages? Did you debug your code with breakpoints? (If you don't know what this means, check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H0XScE08hy8).)

Comment: You should really be toggling a CSS class rather than applying all that styling programmatically.

Comment: When i click the .menu-icon ( the cosnt openMenu ) ,  it creates a div (  the var closeMenu ) ,  but when i click in the div that i just created, nothing happens, it was supposed to remove the div (closeMenu), and yes i checked the console  for any error menssages,  but there was none, and i don't know what the  last thing is, i will watch the video.

Comment: As i said, i'm new to js, and i don't know what is modals , but i will search for it, Thanks!

Comment: I will put all the styling in the CSS later, don't worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add event listener for the closeMenu once it is created while attaching it to the dom. What you are doing is you are accessing that close menu outside the open event listener on page load, The close menu will not be present at that moment on the page.

```
const openMenu = document.querySelector('.menu-icon');

function closeMyMenu() {
  this.remove();
}

//to open
openMenu.addEventListener('click', () =>{
  const _closeMenu = document.getElementById('closeMenu1');
  if (!_closeMenu) {
    var closeMenu = document.createElement('div');
    closeMenu.id = "closeMenu1";
    closeMenu.className = "closeMenu";
    closeMenu.style.width = "400px";
    closeMenu.style.height = "600px";
    closeMenu.style.borderRadius = "6px";
    closeMenu.style.position = "relative";
    closeMenu.style.top = "50%";
    closeMenu.style.left = "50%";
    closeMenu.style.backgroundColor = "#99aaa1";
    closeMenu.addEventListener('click', closeMyMenu);
    document.body.appendChild(closeMenu);
  } else {
    console.log("Close menu already exists");
  }  
});
```

Comment: Oh i understand now what i did wrong, Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

The OP tries to setup close logic on the menu, but at the point the code queries for the menu with `document.querySelector('closeMenu1')`, the element hasn't yet been created.

One solution (there's a better one below) is to add the closure handling after the menu is created, in the click callback that creates it.

```js
const openMenu = document.querySelector('.menu-icon');

//to open
openMenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
  var closeMenu = document.createElement('div');
  closeMenu.id = "closeMenu1";
  closeMenu.className = "closeMenu";
  closeMenu.style.width = "400px";
  closeMenu.style.height = "600px";
  closeMenu.style.borderRadius = "6px";
  closeMenu.style.position = "relative";
  closeMenu.style.top = "50%";
  closeMenu.style.left = "50%";
  closeMenu.style.backgroundColor = "#99aaa1";
  closeMenu.textContent = "Click me to remove";

  // create the closure logic here
  closeMenu.addEventListener('click', () => {
    closeMenu.remove();
  });
  document.body.appendChild(closeMenu);
});

// there's no point in referring to an element with id `"closeMenu1"`
// here, because it doesn't yet exist.
```

```html
<button class="menu-icon">Menu Icon (as a button)</button>
```

Alternatively there's a good comment above that suggests using CSS to show and hide a menu. In that scenario, the open menu would always exist, described in html/css, and the user actions would apply a `display` attribute to show or hide it...

```js
function toggle() {
  const menu = document.getElementById("the-menu");
  menu.style.display = (menu.style.display === "block") ? "none" : "block";
}
```

```css
.menu {
  display: none;

  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #99aaa1;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle()">Toggle Menu</button>
<div id="the-menu" class="menu">This is the menu</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you helping, i already achieved what i wanted, but the CSS thing that you said, is something that i did not know, and i will check it later, i tought the best way of doing this was with js, Also the first code that you send seems to be creating multiples "menus" wich is not very good. but again Thanks